# Python + BeautifulSoup - Text extraction by searching criteria

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

A file contains HTML codes like below (the words 'Registration' and 'Flying' are fixed in the following paragraphs):

```
<TR>
<TD class=CAT2 width="10%">Registration</TD>
<TD class=CAT1 width="20%">02 Mar 2006</TD></TR>

<TR>
<TD class=CAT2 width="10%">Flying</TD>
<TD class=CAT1 width="20%">24 Jun 2005</TD></TR>
```

I want to extract them and put as:

> Registration 02 Mar 2006
>
> Flying 24 Jun 2005

I am using the BeautifulSoup find_next_sibling however it returns nothing. What’s went wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = r"C:\example.html"
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

aa = soup.find_next_sibling(text='Registration')

print aa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
soup.find(text="Registration").findNext('td').contents[0]
```

Comment: Will work if you change `"Registration:"` to `"Registration"`

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
aa = soup.find_next_sibling(text='Registration')
```

is not returning a node in the HTML as you are expecting it would. Instead it is returning a `NoneType`. What you want to do instead is, find the element with `text='Registration'` get it's parent and get the parent's next sibling.

```
aa = soup.find(text='Registration')
par = aa.parent
print par.next_sibling.string
```

You could also achieve your output as:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

row_1 = soup.find('tr')
td = row_1.find('td')
string_1 = td.string + ' ' + td.next_sibling.string #Registration 02 Mar 2006

row_2 = row_1.next_sibling
td = row_2.find('td')
string_2 = td.string + ' ' + td.next_sibling.string #Flying 24 Jun 2005
```

Comment: I have replaced find_next_sibling with find. Have you made that change in your code as well?

Comment: thanks for your efforts, warunsl. it's informative. but i need to use the search criteria here, for example 'Registration ' etc..